# How to post data to server in J2ME? Getting response from server Invalid API Key

Tags: java-me, httpconnection, j2mepolish, midp-2.0

I am posting some data to server but i am getting `{"status":false,"error":"Invalid API Key."}` response from server. My API Key is correct but where is the problem i don't know. Please friends help me. I tried lot but i did not find solution. I have used following code for posting data to server.

```
public void tryingOne(String dtl){

     HttpConnection httpConn = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;

 String url="http://api.geanly.in/ma/index?API-Key="+apikey;

    String details = "&orderInfo={\"booking\":{\"restaurantinfo\":{\"id\":\"5722\"},\"referrer\":{\"id\": \"9448476530\" }, \"bookingdetails\":{\"instructions\":\"Make the stuff spicy\",\"bookingtime\": \"2011-11-09 12:12 pm\", \"num_guests\": \"5\"}, \"customerinfo\":{\"name\":\"Vinodh SS\",   \"mobile\":\"9345245530\",  \"email\": \"vind@gmail.com\",  \"landline\":{ \"number\":\"0908998393\",\"ext\":\"456\"}}}}";
    try {

        System.out.println("url@@@@"+url);
        httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

       DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.openDataOutputStream());
        outStream.write(details.getBytes(),0,details.length());
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

  //Reading Resp. from server
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        is = httpConn.openDataInputStream();
        int chr;
        while ((chr = is.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) chr);
        }


        System.out.println("Response from srvr " + sb.toString());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (httpConn != null) {
            try {
                httpConn.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me friends...
Thanks

Comment: Have you debug on server side?

Comment: i dont know what happning on server because server is not here... but i will ask about that whats going on there...

Comment: Have you tried to post with [encoded URL?](http://sihantech.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/encoding-url-in-j2me/)

Answer (score 1):

For sending data using `HttpConnection` use the class [in this tutorial](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME). It also gets the response from the server.

Comment: ya i used same things.. but still getting {"status":false,"error":"Invalid API Key."}

Answer (score 1):

you need to trim the variable "apikey".

I was getting same problem when connecting with Picasa Server.

Comment: when you apply following line in the explorer's address bar , what it returns ?
http://api.geanly.in/ma/index?API-Key=apikey(key's value)